# Java Optional usage for multi-map

Tags: lambda, java-8, option-type

Continent is a composite Object. Structure is :

```
Continent
--Country
----State
------Town
```

so in this notation:

```
town= Optional.of(continent)
            .map(Continent::getCountry)
            .map(Country::getState)
            .map(State::getTown)
            .orElse(null);
```

this works fine, but when I try to write a general mapper,

```
  public static <T, R> T getFromMapping(R source,
                                      T defaultValue,
                                      Function<?,?>... functions) {
      Optional sourceWrapper = Optional.ofNullable(source);
      for (Function function : functions) {
         sourceWrapper.map(function);
      }
    return (T) sourceWrapper.orElse(defaultValue);
  }
```

and invoke it by

```
 portfolio = getFromMapping(continent, null,
            ((Function<Continent, Country>) Continent::getCountry)
            ((Function<Country, State>) Country::getState),
            ((Function<State, Town>) State::getTown));
```

it compile just fine but don't work. The mapper jump to second step to and said Continent could not cast to country, why? there supposed to be no cast while doing mapping, how to fix it?

Comment: You might want to swap your `T` and `R` to avoid confusion. `java.util.function` has the loose naming convention that `T` and `U` are inputs and `R` is a return value.  You are essentially building a `Function<R,T>`

Comment: Suggestion: if you create variants of `getFromMapping` with fixed numbers of functions, you'll have a typesafe solution and do not need to cast the arguments anymore.

Comment: @HankD Thanks Hank, I've corrected the interface~

Comment: @stholzm yeah, but I just want to make the function flexible to extend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Optional#map` does not modify itself, but returns a new `Optional` instead, so `sourceWrapper` still contains your continent. You should reassign the variable in the for loop:

```
sourceWrapper = sourceWrapper.map(function);
```